# Complex Sort on multiple very large MongoDB Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb database with currently about 30 collections ranging from 1.5gb to 2.5gb and I need to reformat and sort the data into nested groups and dump them to a new collection. This database will eventually have about 2000 collections of the same type and formatting of data.

Data is currently available like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("598392d6bab47ec75fd6aea6"),
"orderid" : NumberLong("4379116282"),
"regionid" : 10000068,
"systemid" : 30045305,
"stationid" : 60015036,
"typeid" : 7489,
"bid" : 0,
"price" : 119999.91,
"minvolume" : 1,
"volremain" : 6,
"volenter" : 8,
"issued" : "2015-12-31 09:12:29",
"duration" : "14 days, 0:00:00",
"range" : 65535,
"reportedby" : 0,
"reportedtime" : "2016-01-01 00:22:42.997926"} {...} {...}
```

I need to group these by regionid > typeid > bid like this:

```
{"regionid": 10000176,
"orders": [
{
  "typeid": 34,
  "buy": [document, document, document, ...],
  "sell": [document, document, document, ...]
},
{
  "typeid": 714,
  "buy": [document, document, document, ...],
  "sell": [document, document, document, ...]
}]
}
```

Here's more verbose a sample of my ideal output format: https://gist.github.com/BatBrain/cd3426c29ce8ca8152efd1fa06ca1392

I have been trying to use the [db.collection.aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to do this, running this command as an initial test step:

```
db.day_2016_01_01.aggregate( [{ $group : { _id : "$regionid", entries : { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },{ $out : "test_group" }], { allowDiskUse:true, cursor:{} })
```

But I have been getting this message, `"errmsg" : "BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB limit."`

I tried looking into how to use the cursor object, but I'm pretty confused about how to apply it in this situation, or even if that is a viable option. Any advice or solutions would be great.

Comment: You're hitting a hard limit here where any document in an aggregation pipeline must not be bigger than 64MB. Plus, you are creating really large documents so you're risking to hit other limits (e.g. 16MB per document) with your approach. So you will need another solution. What's the reason why you are attempting to restructure your data to that format in the first place? Why are you creating loads of different collections with documents of the same structure?

Comment: Im trying to restructure the data to reduce the indexing size(mb) requirements. Any queries will be restricted to region by date at the most inclusive, so I figured by grouping by that field would be best route to go. I only have a 4 core system with 6gb RAM to run this database on atm.

Comment: --EDIT-- Well i just found out I can make a multikey index on each collection which is 63-72mb per collection. So I guess what I wanted to do isnt needed anymore? I will still need to do calculations and averages on large sections of this database, which I imagine will pose the same issue I am having here.

Comment: If you explain what your problem is precisely rather than your solution attempt we might be able to help you better. What kind of data have you got? What sorts of analyses do you want to run? Which problems do you encounter when doing what, etc...